# Create a matrix that have both char and int in java

Tags: java, matrix

I tried to create a matrix to store the information.  For example, if A and Q meet, it would returns -1.  My question is that in a 2D array, there is no way to store both character and int, is there a way to initialize the following matrix in java?

```
   A  R  N  D  C  Q    
A  4 -1 -2 -2  0 -1  
R -1  5  0 -2 -3  1   
N -2  0  6  1 -3  0   
D -2 -2  1  6 -3  0  
C  0 -3 -3 -3  9 -3   
Q -1  1  0  0 -3  5
```

Comment: Arrays in Java only accept integers as indices of an array, so, you the indexing will have to be done in two steps: one to convert the char to the corresponding numeric index, and another to actually access the matrix.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK in this case, the order of the matrix will be changed, that is, in the modified matrix, A and R will be next to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example "A", "R", "N", "D", "C", and "Q" are not members of the matrix, they are axis labels of its indexes. You do not need to store them in the same matrix as the integers.

Create a separate array with the labels, and use it to "translate" an index name (`'A'`, `'R'`, `'N'`, etc.) to a numeric index into the matrix dimension.

One way to do it is to use `String dimLabels = "ARNDCQ"`, and apply [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to it to get the index into the matrix:

```
static final String dimLabels = "ARNDCQ";

char dimChar = 'R';
int dimIndex = dimLabels.indexOf(dimChar);
if (dimIndex >= 0) {
    ... // The index is valid
} else {
    ... // The index name is invalid
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about a Map of Maps?

```
Map<Character, Map<Character, Integer>> matrix = TreeMap<>();
```

You could use other implementations of Map besides TreeMap, but I figure you'd want your keys to be sorted alphabetically (beware of case).

You'd populate your map as you would any map. For example, for the letter A...

```
Map<Character, Integer> mapA = new TreeMap<>();
mapA.put('A', 4);
mapA.put('R', -1);
mapA.put('N', -2);
mapA.put('D', -2);
mapA.put('C', 0);
mapA.put('Q', -1);

matrix.put('A', mapA);
```

To reference AQ, you would invoke `matrix.get('A').get('Q')` and get the desired `-1` as a result.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an own class and you can store the necessary information in it, something like this:

```
class Dot {
    private int value;
    private String rowId;
    private String columnId;

    public Dot(String rowId, String columnId, int value) {
        this.rowId = rowId;
        this.columnId = columnId;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // getter / setters
}
```

Then you can create a `List`, add Dots into list and create a method for `search(comunnId, rowId)`.

```
List martix = new ArrayList<Dot>();
matrix.add(new Dot("A", "Q", -1));
...
```

and the search method:

```
public int search(String comunnId, String rowId) {
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps you to implement what you want.

Comment: How refreshing it is to see an answer actually promoting classes, instead of using arrays or Map<>.

Comment: Array data type does not fit best to this problem.

Comment: The easiest solution is Map<String, Integer> map; then add this to the map: ("AQ", -1). Then get back the value is so easy: map.get("AQ"). But this is not an Object Oriented solution and Java is a strong OO language.

Answer (score 2):

You can associate an array of integers and an order to each character, effectively building your matrix as a map.

```
    Map<Character, int[]> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    dataMap.put('A', new int[] { 4, -1, -2, -2,  0, -1});
    dataMap.put('R', new int[] {-1,  5,  0, -2, -3,  1});
    dataMap.put('N', new int[] {-2,  0,  6,  1, -3,  0});
    dataMap.put('D', new int[] {-2, -2,  1,  6, -3,  0});
    dataMap.put('C', new int[] { 0, -3, -3, -3,  9, -3});
    dataMap.put('Q', new int[] {-1,  1,  0,  0, -3,  5});

    Map<Character, Integer> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
    orderMap.put('A', 0);
    orderMap.put('R', 1);
    orderMap.put('N', 2);
    orderMap.put('D', 3);
    orderMap.put('C', 4);
    orderMap.put('Q', 5);

    int val = dataMap.get('A')[orderMap.get('Q')];
    System.out.println(val);
```